# Paper published in peer-reviewed student journal that appears to have shut down. How should I present evidence of article publication?

Tags: publications

While I was in academia, I co-authored a research paper and submitted it to a peer-reviewed student journal for publication. They sent me a PDF copy of Volume 3, Issue 1 in 2014 as proof.

However, the journal itself appears to have went defunct afterwards. Searching for the journal's official websites reveals PDF copies of their issues from previous years, up to 2013, meaning that the 2014 issue isn't even publicly available.

Nevertheless, since the article *did* get published, I currently have this article listed on my professional resume. In case anyone had any questions about that publication, what proof should I show explaining that the article did get published?

Comment: Who said you needed proof? I'm not sure I would sweat it.

Comment: If the paper is not publicly available then it was not technically published. On the other hand, the only reason I can think of you needing proof for is that being accepted to said journal carries some prestige or lends weight to the paper. Unless your field is very different than mine (which is certainly possoble) then neither is likely for a student journal, even a peer reviewed one.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Not available online does not necessarily mean not publicly available. There could be printed issues lying around somewhere. Of course, for a student journal from 2014, this seems rather unlikely.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Right, I read it as those issues never having been actually published, apart from copies sent to authors (those issues existing is not enough for it to be published. It needs to be available at some libraries or similar).

Comment: A publication in a defunct *student* journal may not help you much. It's good to keep the PDF around, but why would anybody demand proof? It doesn't appear to be a high impact where someone might question if you are indeed the author of it. But for your own interest, it might be worth finding out whether you are allowed to make that PDF publicly available so that someone can *read* find these publications...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the (rare) event of you requiring proof of your publication, you ought to still hold the email communications that connects to the Publisher as evidence; especially the 'acceptance for publication' and 'confirmation of publication' letters.

---

Your issue volume and number look like it's a relatively new journal to which you've submitted your paper. I sure hope that it isn't a predatory one.

Comment: The journal has never asked for money during the publication process, so I doubt it was predatory.